# How to check checkboxes differently depending on parent div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I just made a question about checkboxes, however I need this one last question to finish up.

So let's say I wanted to have default settings for the checkboxes in the following code:

```
<div id="exampleBoxes">
    <p>Example 1</p>
    <fieldset id="field1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="forca" class="checkOne" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="forca" class="checkTwo" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="forca" class="checkThree" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="forca" class="checkFour" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="forca" class="checkFive" />
    </fieldset>

    <p>Example 2</p>
    <fieldset id="field2">
        <input type="checkbox" name="destreza" class="checkOne" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="destreza" class="checkTwo" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="destreza" class="checkThree" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="destreza" class="checkFour" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="destreza" class="checkFive" />
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

I could add a "checked" attribute to have them checked, but how could I make it a certain way where I could make them default checked depending on a class I could keep changing on the #exampleBoxes div?

For instance, if I add a class .methodOne to #exampleBoxes, I would want fieldset#field1 to check the first 3 checkboxes automatically.
But if at any given point .methodOne class changes to .methodTwo, a different number of checks would happen.

Appreciate any insights!

Comment: I am not sure if I understand correctly. However, I cannot figure out any link between giving `.methodOne` and selecting first checkbox's 3? You could have an array reflecting each selection for each class you have registered.

Comment: Whatever code you use to change the class could also call javascript code to change the state of the checkboxes.  Can you show us the code you're using to change the classes of the #exampleBoxes div?

Comment: I'm looking for the simplest ways to check the boxes automatically when the parent div changes classes. In simpler terms.

Comment: You may need to include two or three real examples to ellaborate the best option to go, you can run a function each time you change the classname and evaluate wich one applies.... Or maybe you can store the values on some data attribute, or .... there are many ways

Comment: I will have 5 possible classes which will be changeable by the user by a click, in which I want to change which boxes are checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can trigger an event on class changed to do what you want, for example:

you bind an event

```
$("#exampleBoxes").bind('cssClassChanged', function(){ 
  if ($(this).hasClass("methodOne")){
    //do something
  }else if($(this).hasClass("methodTwo")){
    //do something else
  }
  ...... //all your conditions
})
```

;

and when you change the class, you trigger the event

```
$("#exampleBoxes").addClass('methodOne');
$("#exampleBoxes").trigger('cssClassChanged')
```

Comment: Simple and efficient! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

To check if a class is added/removed to an element from another javascript / jQuery function you may use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver):

- Start  MutationObserver
- listen....
- Stop  MutationObserver

```js
var observer = null;

$(function () {
  $('#exampleBoxes').on('DOMAttrModified', function (e) {
    var a = this;
  });
  $('#btn1').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#exampleBoxes').toggleClass('methodOne');
  });
  $('#btn2').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#exampleBoxes').toggleClass('methodTwo');
  });
  $('#btn3').on('click', function(e) {
    if (observer != null) {
      return;
    }
    observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
      mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        if (mutation.attributeName === "class") {
          var newVal = $(mutation.target).prop(mutation.attributeName);
          alert('DIV exampleBoxes changed class to: ' + newVal);
          
          // Instead of alert call your function according
          // to the value of newVal (class value)
          
          
        }
      });
    });
    var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };
    
    // observe changes for exampleBoxes DIV element
    observer.observe($('#exampleBoxes')[0], config);
  });
  $('#btn4').on('click', function(e) {
    observer.disconnect();
    observer = null;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>

<div id="exampleBoxes">
    <p>Example 1</p>
    <fieldset id="field1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="forca" class="checkOne"/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="forca" class="checkTwo"/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="forca" class="checkThree"/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="forca" class="checkFour"/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="forca" class="checkFive"/>
    </fieldset>

    <p>Example 2</p>
    <fieldset id="field2">
        <input type="checkbox" name="destreza" class="checkOne"/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="destreza" class="checkTwo"/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="destreza" class="checkThree"/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="destreza" class="checkFour"/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="destreza" class="checkFive"/>
    </fieldset>
</div>
<button id="btn1">Toggle class methodOne </button>
<button id="btn2">Toggle class methodTwo </button>
<button id="btn3">Start  MutationObserver</button>
<button id="btn4">Stop  MutationObserver</button>
```